# How ro align this button

Tags: html

Could you please explain me how to align this button at center?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://office.instantticketing.com/pit/scripts/pit-widget-boot.js"></script>
<button onclick="javascript:pitWidgetBootToken('khaxfcarjhtso4h9lubk5ywwcp21386707097031');">
    <span style="text-align: center; line-height: 1.0; font-size: 16px; text-transform: none;">Book now</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that would be to use css; for example:

```
.button_centre {
    margin:auto;
    display:block;
}
```

and html/js/

```
<button onclick="javascript:pitWidgetBootToken('khaxfcarjhtso4h9lubk5ywwcp21386707097031');" class="button_centre">
    <span style="text-align: center; line-height: 1.0; font-size: 16px; text-transform: none;">
        Book now
    </span>
</button>
```

Check out the [Fiddle of this question](http://jsfiddle.net/WLKM6/).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the button in a div and have text-align:center on the div

http://jsfiddle.net/ykZgJ/

```
<div style="text-align:center">
<button onclick="javascript:pitWidgetBootToken('khaxfcarjhtso4h9lubk5ywwcp21386707097031');"><span     style="text-align: center; line-height: 1.0; font-size: 16px; text-transform: none;">Book now</span></button>
</div>
```